# docker does not expose static ip for container

Tags: docker, nginx, ip

i am trying to bind container with `nginx` to ip `172.16.238.10` , but for some reason docker ignores settings in docker-compose

```yaml
#my docker-compose file
version: "3.9"

services:

    nginx:
        build: nginx/
        ports: 
            - 80:80/tcp
        volumes:
            ./dokcer/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            ./dokcer/nginx/conf/hosts:/etc/hosts
            ./docker/project:/var/www/project
        networks:
            app_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10


    php-fpm:
        build: php-fpm/
        ports:
            - 9000:9000/tcp
        volumes:
            ./dokcer/php-fpm/conf/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
            ./dokcer/php-fpm/conf/hosts:/etc/hosts
            ./dokcer/project:/var/www/project
        networks:
            app_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11

networks:
    app_net:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
```

after build and launch, I look at the `docker_app_net` network and `see that the nginx container has ip 172.16.238.2` although I `expected it to be 172.16.238.10`.

what could be the problem? I will be grateful for every answer because I am confused `:c`

Comment: Do you have a reason to want those specific IP addresses?  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in this file, using the Compose-provided `default` network, and letting Docker manage the IP space itself.  Between containers on the same network you can use the Compose service names like `php-fpm` as host names; outside Docker the IP addresses aren't usually reachable and you need to connect to the published `ports:`.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this setup further.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your answer :)
I know that docker allows accessing by container name, but the fact is that I have the domain `project.loc`, which is in the file /nginx/conf.d, this is something like a virtual host. Therefore, I need nginx to have a static ip so that all containers can access `project.loc` 

in other containers / etc / hosts

there is a record:

`172.16.238.10 project.loc`

Comment: You have no way to configure the other containers to refer to different host names in different environments?

Comment: @DavidMaze what do you mean?